# Is it possible in nginx to rewrite a POST request into GET one?

Tags: post, get, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to get the POST variables with JS, but it can only catch GET variables. My idea is to rewrite an POST request into GET one. Is it possible?  The file is static html, and i don't wannt to use php or some script-language to do this.

Comment: This sounds extremely ugly. You should really consider changing other parts of your script/app so that you don't need this hack. What are your trying to accomplish by fetching POST variables with Javascript?

Answer (score -1):

Use reverse proxy. But its an extremely bad fix.